# syntax error, unexpected '{' - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

**---ERROR MESSAGE**

> FatalErrorException in BooksController.php line 66: syntax error,
>   unexpected '{'

**--LINE 66**

```
$book = DB::table('books')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

**---CODE**

```
   public function request(Request $request, $id) {
        $book = DB::table('books')->where('id', $id)->first();
        $user_id = {{ Auth::guard('web')->user()->id }} 
        DB::table('book_requests')->insert(
            ['book_id' => $book->id, 'user_id' => $user_id ]
        );
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `{{ }}` construction in controller, only in a view.

Try this:

```
public function request(Request $request, $id) {
        $book = DB::table('books')->where('id', $id)->first();
        $user_id = Auth::guard('web')->user()->id;
        DB::table('book_requests')->insert(
            ['book_id' => $book->id, 'user_id' => $user_id ]
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** use `{{ }}` **blade syntax** in controller.

You **can use** it in .`blade.php` file only.

`{{ 'string' }}` **means** `<?php echo 'string' ?>`

In controller, just write

```
$user_id = Auth::guard('web')->user()->id;
```

and in view(blade template) file, print it via

```
{{ $user_id }} // equal to <?php echo $user_id; ?>
```

Refer below link for better understanding.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using blade syntax in controller? Remove the blade syntax from controller

```
public function request(Request $request, $id) {
    $book = DB::table('books')->where('id', $id)->first();
    $user_id = Auth::guard('web')->user()->id;
    DB::table('book_requests')->insert(
        ['book_id' => $book->id, 'user_id' => $user_id ]
    );
}
```